# PHP string encoding is not recognized by strpos()?

Tags: php, string, character-encoding, ms-word

I have a binary Word .doc that looks something like this in string format:

```
þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿppp„±¶g œÙ Text in word doc here I'm interested in  [|`ñÿ|Standard1$S_HmHnHsHtHOJPJQJCJEH567>
```

When I echo that string, I can see all the text I'm interested in finding in between unrecognized characters (but those I'm not worried about them since I only want the text). The issue is that PHP does not seem to recognize it as a string and so I cannot search it with `strpos(), strpos(), strchr(), mb_strpos()` all return nothing. No -1, no error in the PHP error log, just nothing.

However, when I call `gettype()` I get string. I suspect this is an encoding issue, but mb_detect_encoding returns UTF-8. I have tried converting it to multiple different encoding types, without avail.

How can I get PHP to search this string? I understand that parsing a Word .doc is more complex of an issue, but for my purposes the plaintext I'm interested in are in the binary data. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Since its encoding is utf8 maybe you want to try mb_strpos http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I mentioned that I had tried that. Absolutely nothing is returned.

Comment: Have you tried with 'UTF-8' as a parameter?

Comment: I just tried it. echo mb_strpos($binaryData, "text", 0, 'UTF-8'); Still nothing.

Comment: And if yes what do you mean by "nothing"? Null? A function must return something or then null.Mb_strpos should return -1 or an integer value.Otherwise you probably have an error somewhere.Use var_dump(mb_strpos("your_haystack",
 "your_needle",
 0,
 "UTF-8")) and tell us what you get

Comment: boolean false is what I'm returning. It does not return true for anything in the string, even " " spaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118643/discussion-between-george-pant-and-anda).

Answer (score 1):

Since you string seems binary encoded and you are only interested in text a quick  solution would be to use `filter_var` to clean the string from non ascii-printable characters.Try using this before searching:

```
$clean_string = filter_var($str,FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the part "Standard1$". php is taking $ as the operator instead of a character. 
**[check here](https://ideone.com/VJINnI)**.

```
<?php

$s = "þÿÿÿÿÿÿÿppp„±¶g œÙ Text in word doc here I'm interested in  [|`ñÿ|Standard1$S_HmHnHsHtHOJPJQJCJEH567>";

$s2 = strpos($s, "interested");
echo $s2;
?>
```

you might want to put a backslash before that $ sign.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How can I search for the "$" to remove it or add anything though? If I try explode($binary, "any character") I get just an array with the same one long string.

Comment: put the string in single quotes (') and that should solve your problem.

Comment: where from and how are you reading this string? if you're declaring this string in your php code, putting the string in single quotes (') should solve your problem.

Comment: Did you mean the binary haystack or the needle? I just did $binaryData = "'" . $binaryData . "'"; and am still getting "false" for strpos()

Comment: the haystack. where is it coming from? are you reading it from a file or db or just copying it from somewhere and pasting in your php source code like `$s = "some pasted text";`?

Comment: I am using a ReportingCloud API that downloads a .doc template into binary form. So no, not copy & pasted. gettype() is string and mb_detect_encoding() is UTF-8.